# mysql query and order by current month

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select records that have the curent month using:

```
SELECT * FROM postdata 
ORDER BY postdate DESC 
WHERE MONTH(postdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
```

The date format for postdate is `YYYY-MM-DD` (`2012-06-30` for example), but unfortunately no records are being returned. Is this the corrent MySQL statement to use?

Comment: your `WHERE` and `ORDER` clauses should be switched

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It isn't fully clear that this is your intent, but it seems likely so I'll contribute as an answer:

Aside from your `ORDER BY` being out of place, you must compare *both* the month and the date.  Since the function `MONTH()` returns only a number 1 through 12, the query would return all records for June of all years, rather than only the current year.  Use both `MONTH(), YEAR()` to compare months for the current year.

```
SELECT * FROM postdata     
WHERE 
  MONTH(postdate) = MONTH(CURDATE())
  AND YEAR(postdate) = YEAR(CURDATE())
ORDER BY postdate DESC
```

Comment: This feels slow, won't this calculate the month and year on EACH row.

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER BY` must come after the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM postdata 
WHERE MONTH(postdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY postdate DESC
```

Think of it like this:

- "Get" all the rows from the table
- Filter those rows with a `WHERE`
- *Then* order that filtered resultset.

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) (stripped down), `WHERE` comes *before* `ORDER BY`;

```
SELECT
    ...
    [WHERE where_condition]
    ...
    [ORDER BY {col_name | expr | position}
      [ASC | DESC], ...]
    ...
```

---

Aside from the problem in your OP, your logic is actually a little flawed; you need to compare both the month *and* the year of the dates, otherwise rows with the same month from any year will be selected. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM postdata 
WHERE 
    MONTH(postdate) = MONTH(NOW())
    AND YEAR(postdate) = YEAR(NOW())
ORDER BY postdate DESC
```

Comment: what is the difference from my query?

Comment: @Sashi What's the difference between your query and, say, Michael's in his answer? I'm really not sure what your point is here. Are you trying to say that the correct solution is only yours to have in your answer?

Comment: At that time aour answers were exactly same

Comment: @Sashi I wouldn't say so. Michael's and my answer gives the solution to the question _with an explanation_, which yours does not. Mine contains a reference to the documentation, and Michael's explains why the OP needs to compare years as well. Your answer simply says "do this", without explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Current month

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_column ,'%Y-%m') =  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m')
```

---

Month filtering you want

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_column ,'%Y-%m') =  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-05')
```

Answer (score 0):

TRy this ::

```
    SELECT * FROM postdata 
      WHERE MONTH(postdate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE) 
    YEAR(postdate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
ORDER BY postdate DESC
```